# Running class in the background

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading

I have a win form that starts a mini server type thing to serve web pages to the local browser, now the problem is, is that when I start it the application obviously won't run because there is a loop that waits for requests, for every request I create a new thread. Now should I create a complete new thread for the entire process or is there another way? The class is in a separate dll file I have created. Alone it works perfectly as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you take a look at the [ThreadPool Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx). It is an easy-to-use option for handling multiple threads:

> The thread pool enables you to use threads more efficiently by providing your application with a pool of worker threads that are managed by the system.

To queue a method for execution simply use the [QueueUserWorkItem Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4yd16hza.aspx):

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state =>
{
    // do some work!
});
```

If you realize that you need more active concurrent threads to serve your clients, call the [SetMaxThreads Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.setmaxthreads.aspx):

```
ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(50, 10);
```

All requests above those numbers for worker threads and I/O threads remain queued until thread pool threads become available.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways here:

1. Async server. More difficult and more performance. http://robjdavey.wordpress.com/2011/02/12/asynchronous-tcp-server-example/
2. One thread per client. Easy to write but not applicable if you have many clients. http://tech.pro/tutorial/704/csharp-tutorial-simple-threaded-tcp-server

don't use loop until requests

Comment: There is only one client and will only ever be one client

Answer (score 1):

I would follow @Thomas suggestion, but adding `waitHandles` to your ThreadPool to manage the callback cycles.

```
WaitCallback classMethod1= new WaitCallback(DoClassMethod1);
bool isQueued = ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(classMethod1, waitHandle[0]);

WaitCallback classMethod2= new WaitCallback(DoClassMethod2);
bool isQueued = ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(classMethod2, waitHandle[1]);

// do this if you want to wait for all requests complated
if (WaitHandle.WaitAll(waitHandles, 5000, false))
  // request completed, show your result. 
else
  // problem.

void DoClassMethod1(object state)
{
  // do your work
  ManualResetEvent mre = (ManualResetEvent)state;
  mre.Set();
}
```